# Removing an item from a many-to-many association in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many

I have a one-directional many-to-many association: the ListDefinition class has the Columns property of type IList, while a column can be part of several ListDefinition-s. The problem is, whenever I try to remove a column from one Columns collection (without deleting it or removing from other ListDefinitions), I'm getting this error:
deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)[Domain.Lists.Definitions.ListColumnDefinition#2]

My mapping is generated via Fluent NH:

```
mapping.HasManyToMany(list => list.Columns)
.AsList(part => part.Column("`index`"))
.Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
```

Here's the generated hbm:

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-access="property" auto-import="true" default-cascade="all" default-lazy="false">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" mutable="true" name="Domain.Lists.Definitions.ListDefinition, Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="`ListDefinition`">
    <id access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore" name="Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <list cascade="all-delete-orphan" name="Columns" table="ListColumnDefinitionToListDefinition" mutable="true">
      <key>
        <column name="ListDefinition_id" />
      </key>
      <index>
        <column name="`index`" />
      </index>
      <many-to-many class="Domain.Lists.Definitions.ListColumnDefinition, Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
        <column name="ListColumnDefinition_id" />
      </many-to-many>
    </list>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're doing, Could you paste the relevant code? (how you delete the entity that is throwing this error)

Comment: I'm *not* deleting an entity. I just do this:
listDefinition.Columns.Remove(column);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure "[all-delete-orphan](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-cascades)" is what you want?

From Section 21.3. Cascading life cycle of the above link:

> In our case, a Child cannot exist
>   without its parent. So if we remove a
>   Child from the collection, we do want
>   it to be deleted. To do this, we must
>   use cascade="all-delete-orphan".